# Azure Custom script extension issue

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to add a custom script extension to a virtual machine and running the below command but it is giving below error.

**Command Used:**

```
Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -Location "East US" -VMName "TINFAD01" -Name "TINFAD01DSC" -StorageAccountName "p1caddraassbdevdevdiag" -StorageAccountKey "XXXXXX" -FileName "TINFAD01.ps1" -ContainerName "dscfiles"| Update-AzVM -Verbose
```

```
**Error** PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -Location "East US" -VMName "TINFAD01" -Name "TINFAD01DSC" -StorageAccountName "p1caddraassbdevdevdiag" -StorageAccountKey "D4o3I7fzY3vuxhRHJ1yAEkOklCIETqmoK voq0ISDMb6wQqyVF5AVaNMl05v9foABwOeQ/+a604HioP7smE3gqQ==" -FileName "TINFAD01.ps1" -ContainerName "dscfiles" | Update-AzVM -Verbose

cmdlet Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: (Type !? for Help.) ResourceGroupName: p1cad-draas-sb-dev-dev Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -Location "East US" -VMName "TINFAD01"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.SetAzureVMCustomScriptExtensionCommand
```

Comment: Please remove your keys from your post if they are real.

Comment: I would also surround my key value in single quotes just in case there is a special character that needs to be passed literally.

Comment: According to script you provide, you do not provide the ```ResourceGroupName``` parameter. Could you please try to provide ```ResourceGroupName```parameter then run the command again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please go through it once and try to explain as much as possible. Thanks!!

Comment: @MohitVerma Could you please check if you have used the right storage key?  According to my test, the command is ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is powershell command to add custom extension to a virtual machine:

```
Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-VMName] <String>
   [-Name <String>]
   -ContainerName <String>
   -FileName <String[]>
   [-StorageAccountName <String>]
   [-StorageEndpointSuffix <String>]
   [-StorageAccountKey <String>]
   [-Run <String>]
   [-Argument <String>]
   [-SecureExecution]
   [-TypeHandlerVersion <String>]
   [-Location <String>]
   [-DisableAutoUpgradeMinorVersion]
   [-ForceRerun <String>]
   [-NoWait]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

By looking at you code it clearly says that you have not provided the resource name:

```
Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -Location "East US" -VMName "TINFAD01" -Name "TINFAD01DSC" -StorageAccountName "p1caddraassbdevdevdiag" -StorageAccountKey "XXXXXX" -FileName "TINFAD01.ps1" -ContainerName "dscfiles"| Update-AzVM -Verbose
```

Please provide the resource group information and see if it helps.

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmcustomscriptextension?view=azps-3.0.0

Feel free to tag me in your conversation for additional help.

Comment: Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: After adding resourceGroupName I get this . 

Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I also gave the entire container read access. 
Made sure the file is present